# two refrigerators on one power outlet

Tags: electrical, socket

Is it allowed to plug in two refrigerators in a power outlet having two sockets? It is 220V.

I heard that there might be some limitations on Amps of the appliances plugged in the outlet, but I'm 100% sure.

If it is not allowed, what are my options? Should I install one more separate outlet line?

Thanks.

Comment: It's almost never disallowed, but to give and accurate direct answer we would need to know country, amperage of actual circuit breaker or fuse, and amperage rating of friidges. Pictures are helpful too.

Comment: Depending on the amps allowed on the circuit, the main concern would be if the two fridges started up at the same exact time.  Most circuits should be able to handle the running amps.  The start up amps of both fridges at the same time might be too much and trip the breaker, but this should not happen often.

Comment: What country are you in, and is this residential or commercial?

Comment: Done this before, but a ring main is rated for 32A... Also depends on the size of the fridges? Normal or American?

Comment: Two sockets on one receptacle is usually assumed to be on the same circuit/breaker.  This is not always the case and you might be dealing with each socket on it's own breaker.

Answer (score 2):

In North America on a 120V circuit you can put two fridges on one circuit so long as the peak current draw of the two combined is not too big for the circuit.  With most modern fridges, on a 20A circuit that won't be a problem.  The circuit should not be used for anything else, whether it's for one or two fridges.  OTOH if you have a 15A circuit and an old fridge that uses 8, 9, 10A, and maybe the circuit also feeds other things ... then no, you probably can't ... unless the second fridge is tiny, like a dorm fridge.

In North America, residential, if you have a 220V appliance it is always because it draws a lot of power.  I've never heard of a residential fridge so big.  But say you have one .... you almost certainly cannot put a second one on the same circuit because the 220V circuit is usually spec'd and built specifically for its one appliance.  You are *allowed* to plug something else into the outlet but chances are you'll pop the breaker ... by design.

If the setting is commercial we can't answer that here.  There may be rules related to workplace safety or regional rules that apply, we don't know.

In 220V countries that I am familiar with, you almost always *can* put two fridges on one circuit.  It would be unusual to have dedicated circuits in countries where A) all power is at 220V and B) most fridges are small. It's fairly normal to have just one or two circuits feeding an entire kitchen.

Comment: Just curious why in paragraph 1 why do you specify "peak" current? Isn't the labelled operating current adequate for calculations due to inrush being handled by inverse-time curve design of circuit breakers?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease TBH I used the term too loosely, I really meant Max current, ie nameplate rating, not motor inrush.   But since you raised the topic, perhaps the combination of two fridges potentially starting together (double inrush) or milliseconds apart (longer inrush) may not be accommodated by some breakers?  And IDK if there is any reasonable way for OP to determine that.  Just thinking aloud in response to your (good) question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, where the electrical code allows multiple receptacles, there is no restriction on the devices that you can plug in as long as each one matches the rating of the receptacle/circuit (which it *should* pretty much by definition if the device is properly designed/certified for the type of plug). Then it is on the user to make sure not to plug in too many things to one circuit, based on the capacity of the circuit. The capacity of the circuit is normally measured in Amperes and is the value on the circuit breaker.

There are certain additional rules. For example, you are not supposed to use more than 80% (US/Canada NEC, may vary in other locations) of a circuit for continuous use, which is why in the US the standard hairdryer (whether $15 or $150) is rated at 1875W (15A x 125V for a standard 15A receptacle, which can be on a 15A or 20A circuit) but a standard portable heater (whether $25 or $100, with or without a fan, ceramic, oil filled, radiator style, etc.) is rated at 1500W (12A x 125V for a standard 15A receptacle on a 15A or 20A circuit).

In the typical configuration, there will not only be a duplex receptacle in one location, but actually *multiple* duplex receptacles. You can easily have anywhere from 2 to 10 duplex receptacles, for a total of 4 to 20 receptacles, throughout a house on one 15A or 20A circuit (US, common in a 1950s or 1960s house). It is on the user to make sure not to overload the circuit. Since typical appliances, **including modern refrigerators**, only use anywhere from a fraction of 1A (phone chargers, most LED lights, laptop computers) to a few Amps (refrigerator *when running*, desktop computer, washing machine), this works out just fine the vast majority of the time. The exceptions are large power tools (which is why a home workshop will often have additional circuits and, in the US, often have 240V circuits) and resistance heat. Resistance heat includes things like hairdryers and toasters (they will max. out a 15A circuit, *but only for a few minutes at a time*) and space heaters. A circuit breaker will normally have a *trip curve* that allows for a moderate overload for a short amount of time. Which means if you plug in a space heater on the living room circuit that also has a few lights and a TV, the total (1500W for the space heater plus a few hundred W for everything else) will be just fine. And if you run a laser printer on the same circuit as a refrigerator, a freezer, a desktop computer and half the lights in the house then you may get a moderate overload (and a corresponding lights dimming, etc.) for a few seconds when the laser printer starts up - because for those few seconds the circuit is overloaded - but the rest of the time everything is OK and the breaker never trips. (And eventually you get your electrician to split the circuit so that your computer and printers are separate from everything else.)

There is another exception of sorts - hardwired appliances. For hardwired devices you (a) have to make sure the total specifications for all the devices is within the capacity of the circuit and (b) (at least in the US) you can only have general purpose receptacles on the same circuit if the hardwired devices use < 50% of the capacity of the circuit. Typically this means that hardwired lighting can be on the same circuit as ordinary receptacles but that if you have a circuit with a dishwasher, disposal or similar appliance that often it needs a dedicated circuit.

Back the original question: refrigerators. I am having a bit of trouble finding definitive answers as to maximum power/current usage by a refrigerator. In a quick search (via Home Depot, multiple brands), I can only find the total power consumption for a year (typically 700 - 750 kWh for a 25 cubic foot side-by-side - i.e., typical US big refrigerator). That works out to about 80W if run continuously, or less than 1A (less than 0.5A at 220V). But refrigerators will use very little power except when the compressor is running. With a 25% duty cycle that would be 320W (< 3A at 120V, < 2A at 220V), though likely higher current for a few seconds at compressor startup. So based on rough calculations, if you allow 4A per refrigerator on a 220V circuit you will likely be just fine. And probably even less than that. Check your breaker size. A quick search shows that for at least some 220V (230V, 240V, etc.) areas that a typical circuit breaker is 13A to 16A, in which case multiple refrigerators should be absolutely no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a typical U.S. receptacle that looks like this: [image]
then you likely have two 120 volt receptacles on a single 15 or 20 amp circuit. Just two typical modern 18cf fridges/freezers that draw 6 to 8 amps each aren't going to trip a circuit breaker. But this circuit may or may not feed other outlets, so you need to identify if other outlets and what other devices might otherwise cause an overload.

The problem is Electricians need to protect their reputation. Somebody shows me two fridges/freezers, points at a specific receptacle that I know is a dedicated outlet and I say "no problem". He plugs those two fridges into a different garage outlet, not dedicated, plugs a portable heater into the same circuit and goes on vacation and comes home to spoiled food. Suddenly it's my fault, and he tells people I do awful work.

So when people ask me I say "don't do that, it's not a good idea", then you look in my garage and I've run the actual numbers, and have two freezers and a fridge on the same circuit.

Comment: I agree. You always have to protect yourself from others' stupidity.